# How to call function with embeded event

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

This is, what I was looking for :-)  It is working now, but I dont understand to whole code. For example to line with arguments[0] || {}...

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {

  // extend the options from pre-defined values:
  var options = $.extend({
      callback: function() {},
      input: "",
      url: ""
  }, arguments[0] || {});

  // call the callback and apply the scope:
  $(document).on("keyup", options.input, function(){
    options.callback.call(this);
  });
};

$('#test_input').myPlugin({      
  callback: function() {
      console.log($(this).val() );
  },
  input: "#test_input",
  url: "example.php"      
});

</script>
<?php

echo "<input type=text id=test_input maxlength=50 size=25>";
echo "<div id=test_obsah></div>";
```

Comment: why are you complicating things in life? what are you trying to achieve that is not achievable in a plain, Jquery way?

Comment: I have edited my question...

Answer (score 1):

This will only add `keyup` event.

```
$.fn.Example = function(fn) {
 $(document).on("keyup", this, fn);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#test_input").Example(function() { 
    // myfunction, when keyup event is triggered in #test_input 
  });
});
```

This one, you can add any event...

```
$.fn.Example = function(input) {
 $(document).on(input.event, this, input.fn);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#test_input").Example({
  fn: function() { 
    // myfunction, when keyup event is triggered in #test_input 
  },
  event: "keyup"
 });
});
```

The `this`keyword in your Jquery extension points to `#test_input` dom element.

**UPDATE**

And this will accept multiple events...

```
$.fn.Example = function(input) {
   for (var ev in input) {
     if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(ev)) {
       $(document).on(ev, this, input[ev]);
     }
}

};

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#test_input").Example({
  keyup: function() { 
    // event function here
  },
  focusin: function() { 
    // event function here
  },
  focusout: function() { 
    // event function here
  },
 });
});
```

Comment: you can accept the answer if it fits your needs, its a way of saying thanks :)

Comment: It didnt help me. My problem is much more complicated. I will try to explain. I have to handle more inputs with function Example. This Example function contains more events (focusin, focusout, keyup, etc...). So if I assign my Example function to any input - Example(input) - everything is ok. But sometimes, I need to handle event keyup outside of function. So I need to react to keyup in Example function...

Comment: I dont completely understand, but please take a look at my update and see if that is what you meant..